# Unable to access libraries from virtual environment in Jupyter Notebook on Windows

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, virtualenv, python-3.10

I'm facing an issue where I'm unable to access libraries from my virtual environment when running Jupyter Notebook on Windows. Despite activating the virtual environment and installing the required packages, Jupyter Notebook does not recognize the libraries. Here's a breakdown of the problem:

Steps I've Taken:

1. Activated virtual environment using the command: `C:\path\to\your\virtualenv\Scripts\activate`.
2. Verified virtual environment activation with the environment name appearing in the command prompt.
3. Installed necessary packages, including TensorFlow, within the activated virtual environment using: `pip install -r requirements.txt`.
4. Attempted to import these libraries in Jupyter Notebook without success.

Error Message:

When attempting to import a library in Jupyter Notebook, I encounter an ImportError stating that the module cannot be found. For example, running `import tensorflow as tf` results in a "ModuleNotFoundError."

Additional Information:

- I am running Windows 11.
- The virtual environment contains the required packages.
- Python version: `3.10.10`.
- Jupyter Notebook version: `6.5.4`.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights into why Jupyter Notebook is not recognizing the libraries from the virtual environment? Your guidance and expertise would be immensely appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably run the activation command from CMD, which has nothing to do with Jupyter Notebooks. You should select the desired environment from inside the Notebooks.

If you are running it on a browser, `Kernel` -> `Change kernel` and choose the one you need. If you are running it on VS Code, it gives an option to select the kernel when you open the `ipynb` file.